# Call function from another Controller Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to using angular js and i have declare many controller and now i want to user function of one controller into another controller. here is my sample code.

```
app.controller('Controller1',function($scope,$http,$compile){
    $scope.test1=function($scope)
    {
          alert("test1");
    }
});

app.controller('Controller2',function($scope,$http,$compile){
    $scope.test2=function($scope)
    {
          alert("test1");
    }
});
app.controller('Controller3',function($scope,$http,$compile){
  ///
});
```

Now i want to call test2 function inside controller3.
Can anybody help..
Thanks in Avance... :)

Answer (score 13):

You can't call a method from a controller within a controller. You will need to extract the method out, create a service and call it. This will also decouple the code from each other and make it more testable

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app', [])
        .service('svc', function() {
            var svc = {};

            svc.method = function() {
                alert(1);
            }

            return svc;
        })
        .controller('ctrl', [
            '$scope', 'svc', function($scope, svc) {
                svc.method();
            }
        ]);
})();
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FQnthYpxgxAiIJYa69hu?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Best way is write a service and use that service in both controllers. see the documentation [Service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

If you really want to access controller method from another controller then follow the below option:
emitting an event on scope:

```
function FirstController($scope) {  $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {});}

function SecondController($scope) {  $scope.$emit('someEvent', args);}
```

Comment: Yes But i we have already written code with lots of controller so now i have to call one function which is in another controller.

Comment: Thats fine. only you need is move that common function to a service and call it from required controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is a constructor, it will create a new instance if for example used in a directive.

You can still do what you wanted, assuming that your controllers are in the same scope, just do:

Note they must be in the **same scope**, could still work if a child scope was not isolated.
The directive's definition:

```
{
    controller: Controller1,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl1',
    link: function($scope) {

        $scope.ctrl1.test1(); // call a method from controller 1
        $scope.ctrl2.test2(); // created by the directive after this definition
        $scope.ctrl3.test3(); // created by the directive after this definition
    }
}

....
{
    controller: Controller2,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl2',
    link: function($scope) {
        $scope.ctrl1.test1(); // created earlier
        $scope.ctrl2.test2(); // ...
        $scope.ctrl3.test3(); // created by the directive after this definition
    }
}

....
{
    controller: Controller3,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl3',
    link: function($scope) {
        $scope.ctrl1.test1();
        $scope.ctrl2.test2();
        $scope.ctrl3.test3();
    }
}
```

This should work.